# Use emacs version control with git on Windows

Tags: windows, git, emacs

I'm in the unfortunate position of having to use windows (windows 7) on a work computer that I can't tinker too much with. I prefer to use emacs. I'm just getting into git, and I'd like to be able to work with it through emacs. It seems like the simplest solution would be to use emacs' vc [described here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/VersionControl). I've done the following:

Installed [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/emacsbinw64/) version of emacs for windows. 
Installed git from [here](http://git-scm.com/)
Tried calling vc-directory using  c-x v d.

But then I get the error message "...No such file or directory, git"

I can I make emacs speak to git on Windows, without having to install anything else?

Comment: Find the variable that controls the git program and set the value to the absolute path of the `git` executable on your hard drive; or, adjust the Windows path to include the `git` executable.  It *probably* looks something like `vc-git-program` -- e.g., `(setq vc-git-program "path/to/my/git/executable")`  A brief grep of the source code also turned up `git-program`, so do a little bit of Googling using those options.

Comment: Note that the executable will probably be called `git.exe`, not simply `git`. Make sure to include the full file name, including extension.

Comment: Thanks that helped - now I'm getting the error "vc-git-stash-list: Wrong type argument: arrayp, nil" Any guess how best to debug that?

Comment: Never mind I got it! I had linked to the bash executable. Thanks.